# How to get the encryption domain?

Tags: vpn, ipsec

we want to setup IPSec in linode to connect to a data supplier company. They require as to provide the domain ip and encryption domain. How do we get this encryption domain, is it the broadcast domain?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/381057/vpn-encryption-domain

"Encryption domain refers to the range of IP addresses of the hosts which will be participating in the encrypted VPN."  

Hope this helps a little. 

I am curios, is the Linode side going to act like the client for the IPSec VPN Tunnel?

Comment: This may also help you setup IPSec. It is a guide for setting up IPSec on a Ubuntu VM hosted on Linode. http://zhangyangjing.github.io/blog/2013/01/23/setup-vpn-l2tp-over-ipsec-on-ubuntu-with-linode-vps/

Comment: @Canadian_Republican Ah, its clear to me now! Thanks for the help, really appreciate it. I think so yes, the linode acts as a client. Also thank you for the guide. Can you add it as answer so I can approve it? Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link may clear up the meaning of "Encryption Domain": https://serverfault.com/questions/381057/vpn-encryption-domain

"Encryption domain refers to the range of IP addresses of the hosts which will be participating in the encrypted VPN."

This link may also help! It is a guide for setting up IPSec on a Ubuntu VM hosted on Linode: https://zhangyangjing.github.io/blog/2013/01/23/

Best Wishes

Comment: https://zhangyangjing.github.io/blog/2013/01/23/ link is broken